# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'digitalio' HELP

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, circuitpython

I have been following a YouTube tutorial on how to setup the Raspberry Pi Pico H as a midi device. While programming, I came accross an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'digitalio'`. I'm using a mac with thonny IDE and I cant seem to find any help for this issue. ive tried installing it via pip and pip3. I am using circuit python but it also doesnt work on micro python. It's most likely an easy fix but my smooth brain cant figure it out.

Comment: The digitalio module I know of is to facilitate IO on the GPIO pins. Was the error during the install or while running your own code?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question. You need to install the Adafruit_Blinka library from the tools tab. My brain is SMOOOOTH